# How one firebase user can search another firebase user by entering email in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore

I want one user to enter another user's email and search for that account in the firebase

What is the code for it

And also how to connect firebase users among themselves for chatting purpose

Comment: how? have you done any research for this? please dont say no, because I guarantee you can find something on it! its pretty straight forward.

Comment: if you have any suggestion than give it to me.

Comment: Are you adding your users to Firebase database on their sign up?

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, when you add the users data into firebase add them under their own email id. like :

Create a model class "User" with the fields you required.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
User user= new User("UserName", "User@email.com");
mDatabase.child("User@email.com").setValue(user);
```

So in firebase, it will look like this

```
Users
 MyUser@email.com
    Email:  "User@email.com" 
    Fullname:  "UserName"
```

Now if other users have to search for users by giving email id, just

```
DatabaseReference ref= mDatabase.child("User@email.com");

 ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    User user= dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
    // and user.getName() for getting the name
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

 }
 });
```

In this way, you can search for users with their email id very easy.

Now for connecting users for chatting, you have to create a common child that both of them can access, like create a child with key "user1email-user2email". then Listen for child events for that child in both the users and all the message that comes in that child will be shared with each other.